# AMQ+Camel+SMPP Connection binding status for logging

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, jsmpp

I am using amq+camel+smpp for working with SMSC. I used SMPP as camel coponent and use these endpoints in routes. I want to monitor on SMPP connection binding, logs every SMSC bind and unbind in separate file than activemq.log.

Kindly guide me in approaching the mentioned event scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring log4j - http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j.html

Comment: Yes! I am using log4j for logging purpose and also getting bind send receive logs in activemq.log file.    But I want to configure something in camel.xml routes config file so that I may log bind response in separate file than activemq.log.